# Return of Child Component within useEffect and Fetch not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm facing a weird problem. The next code returns correctly inside its useEffect and fetch functions... Nevertheless, the child component is not being rendered. I think it might be because of the map(), but i'm not even sure about it.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
const FilesComponent = () => {
    let result = useRef({
        files: [],
        folders: []
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect...');
        fetch('http://192.168.1.36:3001/api/files/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiYmxhY2tvdXQiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImJsYWNrb3V0QGRvbWFpbi5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDkxMjk4OTMsImV4cCI6MTY0OTIxNjI5MywiaXNzIjoiY2xvdWRsaXRlLXR5cGVzY3JpcHQifQ.i6ik5YTxahBWwKVJdWJUw6dR4vAkwM4ytc-3eSBSzoQ'
            },
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            dispatch({type: 'ChangeMessage',
                files: data.data.files,
                folders: data.data.folders
            });
            const action = {
                type: 'ChangeMessage'
            };
            result.current = reducer({}, action);
            console.log(result.current);
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <ul className="files-list">
                    {
                        result.current.files.map(file => <File href={'https://www.google.com/'} key={file.name} value={file}/>)
                    }
                    {
                        result.current.folders.map(folder => <File href={'https://www.google.com/'} key={folder.name} value={folder}/>)
                    }
                    </ul>
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        });
    }, [result]);
    return (
        <>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Let's start with the obvious question.. Why do you need to render from within a `useEffect`?

Comment: I use the useEffect hook in order to keep track of the state, if it changes i do need to re render the component

Comment: Make a function with the code in useEffect and call it inside useEffect, give proper dependencies. Also, you are using multiple return, one with data and one with fragments. Also, remove your bearer token from the example above.

Comment: Thank you Ritiki. As soon as possible I will try it.

Comment: I tried and it works perfectly without auth bearer. How could I do it with a bearer token?